How to generate access tokens for power BI report?
I need to generate embed access token for a power bi report with Service principal or AD application.
I just want to use my AD username and password.

I am sharing two sample codes.
Python:
import requests

# Constants
username = 'YOUR_POWER_BI_USERNAME'  # Power BI username
password = 'YOUR_POWER_BI_PASSWORD'  # Power BI password
workspace_id = 'YOUR_WORKSPACE_ID'   # Power BI workspace ID
report_id = 'YOUR_REPORT_ID'         # Power BI report ID

# Authenticate and get access token (user credentials)
def get_access_token():
    auth_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token'
    auth_data = {
        'grant_type': 'password',
        'client_id': 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
        'client_secret': 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
        'resource': 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api',
        'username': username,
        'password': password,
        'scope': 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default'
    }
    response = requests.post(auth_url, data=auth_data)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json()['access_token']

# Generate Embed Token
def generate_embed_token(access_token):
    embed_url = f'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{workspace_id}/reports/{report_id}/GenerateToken'
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    body = {
        'accessLevel': 'View'
    }
    response = requests.post(embed_url, headers=headers, json=body)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json()

# Get Embed Token
access_token = get_access_token()
embed_token_data = generate_embed_token(access_token)
print(f"Embed Token: {embed_token_data['token']}")
print(f"Embed URL: {embed_token_data['embedUrl']}")


JavaScript
npm install axios

const axios = require('axios');
const qs = require('qs');

// Constants
const username = 'YOUR_POWER_BI_USERNAME';  // Power BI username
const password = 'YOUR_POWER_BI_PASSWORD';  // Power BI password
const workspaceId = 'YOUR_WORKSPACE_ID';   // Power BI workspace ID
const reportId = 'YOUR_REPORT_ID';         // Power BI report ID

// Function to get access token
async function getAccessToken() {
    const authUrl = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token';
    const authData = {
        grant_type: 'password',
        client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
        client_secret: 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
        resource: 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api',
        username: username,
        password: password,
        scope: 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default'
    };

    try {
        const response = await axios.post(authUrl, qs.stringify(authData), {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        });
        return response.data.access_token;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error getting access token:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}

// Function to generate embed token
async function generateEmbedToken(accessToken) {
    const embedUrl = `https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/${workspaceId}/reports/${reportId}/GenerateToken`;
    const body = {
        accessLevel: 'View'
    };

    try {
        const response = await axios.post(embedUrl, body, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error generating embed token:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}

// Main function
async function embedReport() {
    try {
        const accessToken = await getAccessToken();
        const embedTokenData = await generateEmbedToken(accessToken);

        console.log(`Embed Token: ${embedTokenData.token}`);
        console.log(`Embed URL: ${embedTokenData.embedUrl}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error embedding report:', error);
    }
}

// Run the function
embedReport();

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/powerbi-client@2.18.0/dist/powerbi.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="reportContainer" style="height: 600px;"></div>

    <script>
        // Replace with actual embed token and embed URL
        const embedToken = 'YOUR_EMBED_TOKEN';
        const embedUrl = 'YOUR_EMBED_URL';

        // Configuration
        const config = {
            type: 'report',
            tokenType: powerbi.models.TokenType.Embed,
            accessToken: embedToken,
            embedUrl: embedUrl,
            id: 'YOUR_REPORT_ID',
            settings: {
                filterPaneEnabled: true,
                navContentPaneEnabled: true
            }
        };

        // Embed the report
        const reportContainer = document.getElementById('reportContainer');
        powerbi.embed(reportContainer, config);
    </script>
</body>
</html>

